# Bill Of Materials calculations in R

Tags: r, function, recursion, accumulate

I need to create a recursive function to iteratively calculate the accumulative costs of items in the bill of items given that each item belongs to a specific level, where the levels present the production levels from level n to level 0 (finished product). My data frame is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9"),
  quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4,1, 1),
  price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 0, 10, 0, 4, 0),
  itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B","A", "C"),
  productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1,1, 0)
)
```

I want to create a new column where the total prices will be calculated. The logic of my calculations is:

```
Level 3 =>i1 final_price= i1 price * i1 quantity
                 i2 final_price= i2 price * i2 quantity
                 i3 final_price= i3 price * i3 quantity
                 i4 final_price= i4 price * i4 quantity
Level 2 => i5 final_price= i5 quantity *{(i1 price * i1 quantity)+(i2 price * i2 quantity)+(i3 price * i3 quantity)+(i4 price * i4 quantity)}
Level 1 => i7 final_price= i7 quantity *{(i5 final_price)+(i6 price * i6 quantity)}
Level 0 => i9 final_price= i9 quantity *{(i7 final_price)+(i8 price * i8 quantity)}
```

my purpose is to find the accumulated values of price where price=0 and assign it to final_price after multiplying it by the quantity

I tried finding the solution using the accumulative method but I think it would be better to use a recursive function and call it to get the result.

Comment: I'm guessing because it seems there's an incomplete specification that you expect us to use the "level 2" rule on "i6" and the level 1 rule on "i8". At the moment the level 2 rule is only defined for I5 and the level 1 rule is only defined for i7. I get the impression that this is trying to calculate a cost for assemblages of sub-components that may have multiple contributions to a final cost. It seems awkward in the extreme to do this in one dataframe. Seems that it should be handled with a hierarchy of dataframes. Also pleas of urgency are generally seen as demanding rather than motivating.

Comment: What is the expected answer?

Comment: If you do not respond promptly, how are we to believe that this is urgent?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Yes, I was trying to calculate the cost of an assemblage of sub-assemblies at different production levels and contributing to the finished product per the given hierarchy from down (n) to top (0).
I was trying to find a way to create a recursive function to solve this but every time either the code didn't stop running or the result was 0.
I flagged it urgent because I need it today to finish other similar calculations I started working on in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

With my background from manufacturing, I believe that there could be some typo in the dataframe. As it is urgent, I try my best to help. I modified the itemtype to fix the BOM hierarchy. My experiment tells me that it should be as below.

```
df <- data.frame(
  item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9"),
  quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4,1, 1),
  price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 0, 10, 0, 4, 0),
  itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A","B", "C"),
  productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1,1, 0),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
df$final_price=0
maxLevel=max(df$productionlevel)
df[df$productionlevel==maxLevel,'final_price']=df[df$productionlevel==maxLevel,2]*df[df$productionlevel==maxLevel,3]

for (i in (maxLevel-1):1)
{
  tmpdf=df[df$productionlevel==i, ]
  for (itemtype in tmpdf$itemtype)
  {
    item_id=tmpdf[tmpdf$itemtype==itemtype, 'item_id']
    cost=sum(df[df$itemtype==itemtype & df$productionlevel==(i+1), 'final_price'])
    manufacturecost=ifelse(df[df$item_id==item_id, 3]==0, 1 , df[df$item_id==item_id, 3])
    df[df$item_id==item_id, 'final_price']=df[df$item_id==item_id, 2]*manufacturecost*ifelse(cost==0,1,cost)
  }
}
df[df$productionlevel==0,'final_price']=sum(df[df$productionlevel==1,'final_price'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  item_id quantity price itemtype productionlevel final_price
1      i1        2     2        A               3           4
2      i2        2     5        A               3          10
3      i3        5     3        A               3          15
4      i4        1     7        A               3           7
5      i5        1     0        A               2          36
6      i6        1    10        B               2          10
7      i7        4     0        A               1         144
8      i8        1     4        B               1          40
9      i9        1     0        C               0         184
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried in a very basic way where the number of levels are already known:

```
df <- data.frame(
    item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9"),
    quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4,1, 1),
    price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0),
    itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A","B", "C"),
    productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1,1, 0),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

df$final_price=0
maxLevel=max(df$productionlevel)
df[df$price != 0, 'final_price'] <- df[df$price != 0, 'quantity'] * df[df$price != 0, 'price']
df[df$productionlevel == 2 & df$itemtype != "A", 'final_price'] <- sum(df[df$productionlevel == 3, 'final_price']) * df[df$productionlevel == 2 & df$itemtype != "A", 'quantity']

df[df$productionlevel == 1 & df$itemtype != "A", 'final_price'] <- sum(df[df$productionlevel == 2, 'final_price']) * df[df$productionlevel == 1 & df$itemtype != "A", 'quantity']

df[df$productionlevel == 0 & df$itemtype != "A", 'final_price'] <- sum(df[df$productionlevel == 1, 'final_price']) * df[df$productionlevel == 0 & df$itemtype != "A", 'quantity']
```

The resulting data frame was:

```html
      item_id quantity price itemtype productionlevel final_price
1      i1        2     2        A               3           4
2      i2        2     5        A               3          10
3      i3        5     3        A               3          15
4      i4        1     7        A               3           7
5      i5        1    10        A               2          10
6      i6        2     0        B               2          72
7      i7        4     4        A               1          16
8      i8        1     0        B               1          82
9      i9        1     0        C               0          98
```

I need to make these calculations more generic without specifying the levels and item types.